# Vuex Mutation cant update state with localstorage

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, local-storage, store, vuex

I am creating an App that implements JWT using Vue + Vuex,

Every thing works fine until I used **localStorage**.

Here's my code:

**store.js**

```
import constants from './constants';

*state*
state = {
  token: constants.loginAstoken || constants.token
}

*mutation*
[UPDATE_TOKEN]: (state, {token, sub}) => {
  if(!sub) constants.setToken(token);
  else constants.setLoginAsToken(token);

  token = constants.token;

  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + state.token;
}
```

**constants.js**

```
export function setToken(token) {
  localStorage.setItem('token', token);
}

export function loginAsToken(token) {
  localStorage.setItem('login-as-token', token);
}

export const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || "";
export const loginAsToken = localStorage.getItem('login-as-token') || "";
```

Now as I consume my API, and it returned the correct token but inside the **mutation** `state.token` is still `null`.

Is there any thing that I've missed or is it just the limitation?

anyway i've turned `strict:true` but after reading the strict mode there's no restriction for it in using side effects(*maybe? to my understanding*) in mutation

any answer would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should take a look at `vuex-persist`. It's a simple library which stores and automatically refills your Vuex store based on e.g. LocalStorage. You can also define which properties are persisted and which are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem the mutation function takes only 2 params ( state and payload ) [DOC](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#mutations), you re passing a third one that will be undefined. To fix this use the payload as object like:

```
[UPDATE_TOKEN]: (state, { token, sub }) => {
```

Second problem you re changing the token param value instead of the state:

```
[UPDATE_TOKEN]: (state, token="", sub="false") => {
  if(!sub) constants.setToken(token);
  else constants.setLoginAsToken(token);

  token = constants.token;  <====

  CHANGE TO

  state.token = token;

  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + state.token;
}
```

Comment: Yes. ive updated my code. 
but the question still remains as to why doesn't it update the state to the constant.token

Comment: constants.token value is set during page load and will never change. Use the param value instead

Comment: I see, didn't notice it. shoudlve used a function instead